# Does it make sense to use const with an object that only has constant members?

Tags: c++, constants

If a class has const members only:

```
struct A {
    const int n;
    const std::string s;
    void f() const;
};
```

Are the following groups of definitions equivalent?

```
A a1 {...};
const A a2 {...};

A& ref1 = a1;
const A& ref2 = a1;
const A& ref3 = a2;
```

Is `const` redundant in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Const member variables rarely make sense in the first place.

---

> Are the following groups of definitions equivalent?
>
> ```
> A a1 {...};
> const A a2 {...};
>
> A& ref1 = a1;
> ```

Technically no, they are not equivalent because you cannot do:

```
A& ref1 = a2;
```

Comment: "... rarely make sense..." why? Is that your personal opinion? The last example is not correct indeed, but would be if const is redundant.

Comment: @m.alessandrini `The last example is not correct indeed, but would be if const is redundant.` Hence we can deduce that the const is not redundant. `Is that your personal opinion?` Yes, and an opinion shared by many others.

Comment: Well I think const members are essential in the opposite case, when an object has both members that cam change and others that must be constant. It's also an important indication for compiler optimization. But I'm interested in the rationale of the opinion you promote, have you got some links?

Comment: @m.alessandrini - There are alternatives to const member variables that are usually easier to manage. Such as making the members `private` so they cannot be accessed outside the class, only accessing them through `const` getters. It's one thing for a `class`/`struct` type to constrain how users interact with its members. It's another thing entirely to constrain how member functions of that class are implemented (which is what `const` members do) - if a member function of a class can't be trusted to maintain class state sensibly, you have problems `const` data members don't address.

Comment: @m.alessandrini `It's also an important indication for compiler optimization` that's a common misconception. Runtime const quite rarely helps optimisation.

Comment: @eerorika you keep spitting truths like an oracle. For example a field where I'm sure it affects optimization is embedded system, where it can make the difference of a variable allocated in RAM vs. flash

Comment: @m.alessandrini non-static member variables are stored within the object. Nothing prevents you from storing an object in flash whether its members are const or not since you can make the object itself const instead. I've never seen a system where constness of member variables has affected where instances of the class are stored. If there is such obscure system, I doubt that would change my experience that it's rare.

Comment: @eerorika but indeed, maybe I didn't formulate my question well, I was wondering if an object with all const members would be treated by the compiler as if it had a "const" applied to the whole object, even if you don't write it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in your title:

> Does it make sense to use const with an object that only has constant members?

IMHO you should decide whether you make a variable `const` or not independently of their members being `const` or not. The reason for that is documentation, semantics and consistency, and therefore maintainability.

So if your intent is that this part of the code won't make changes to the variable then add `const` independently of the fact that you are currently not able to do any changes to the member variables.

You never know if you might extend that class with none `const` members in the future, or that you need to remove the `const` qualifier of one of its members and then the *constness* that was before given by all members being `const` won't fully apply anymore.

Comment: I agree. I was just curious if the compiler would treat them exactly the same, but I guess one should inspect the assembly code generated by the various compilers.